# to convert string into TextBox control type

Tags: asp.net

to convert string in to TextBox type
i used following code

```
protected void txtNumber_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int num = Convert.ToInt16(txtNumber.Text);
    for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
    {
        String a = System.String.Concat("TextBox", i);

        TextBox dt1 =(TextBox)(this.FindControl(a);


    }
}
```

but in dt1 value remains null instead of 'a'.

Comment: is the [unmatched left parenthesis](http://xkcd.com/859/) intentional?

Answer (score 1):

Chances are you don't have a textbox with exactly the right ID then.

But it would be better to use an array or a list to start with... then you could use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    TextBox tb = textBoxes[i];
    // Use tb
}
```

There's no point in looking something up by a string when you've actually got a sequence of consecutive numbers... that's exactly the use case for arrays and lists.

Also note that this code:

```
String a = System.String.Concat("TextBox", i);
```

is rather more simply written as:

```
string a = "TextBox" + i;
```